# Javascript arrays, converting celsius to fahrenheit

Tags: javascript

I need to convert 6 Celsius temperatures to Fahrenheit. I need to also calculate the average temperatures. I must use 2 arrays in my solution. I think I'm really close to finding answer here. I'm new to JavaScript.

```
var numIn1 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for January in    Celsius"));
var numIn2 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for February in Celsius"));
var numIn3 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for March in Celsius"));
var numIn4 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for April in Celsius"));
var numIn5 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for May in Celsius"));
var numIn6 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for June in Celsius"));
var degree = new Array(numIn1, numIn2, numIn3, numIn4, numIn5, numIn6);
var Average = 0;
var Total = 0;
for(i = 0; i < degree.length; i++) {
  Total = Total + degree[i];
}

function convert(degree) {
  var i;
  if(degree == "C") {
    i = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
  } else {
    i = (document.getElementById("f").value - 32) * 5 / 9;
    document.getElementById("c").value = Math.round(x);
  }
}
Average = Total / degree.length;
alert(degree[0]);
alert(degree[1]);
alert(degree[2]);
alert(degree[3]);
alert(degree[4]);
alert(degree[5]);
alert(Average);
alert(Math.round(Average));
```

Comment: 1) Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map . 2) the convert() function you wrote is not using the array you built earlier.  3) You named both the array and the parameter to the convert function "degree". Consider giving these different names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Hope it help!

```js
var arr = new Array(6);
     var sum = 0;
     var Average = 0;

     for(var i = 0 ; i < 6; i++){
        var month = '';
        if(i==0) month = "January"; 
        if(i==1) month = "February";
        if(i==2) month = "March";
        if(i==3) month = "April";
        if(i==4) month = "May";
        if(i==5) month = "June";
        arr[i] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter temperature for " + month + " in Celsius"));

        sum += arr[i];
        Average = sum/arr.length;
     }

     for(var j = 0 ; j < arr.length; j++){
        alert("Convertion of: " +arr[j]+" to Fahrenheit is: "+ convertToF(arr[j]));
     }


     alert("The Average is: "+ Math.round(Average));
     alert("The Sum is: "+ sum);


     function convertToF(cTempVal) {
      var fTempVal = (cTempVal * (9 / 5)) + 32;
       return fTempVal;
        
    }
```